# Alterar regional para “pt-br” datepicker com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Gostaria de alterar a reginal para "pt-br" no meu datepicker, estou usando AngularJS.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker />
<br/>
{{ date }}

var myApp= angular.module('app', []);
myApp.directive('datepicker', function() {


return {  
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
  $(el).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        var date = Date.parse(dateText) || 0;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
      });
    }
  });
} 

};
});
```

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o respectivo arquivo de locale no cabeçalho da página, conforme o exemplo:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
```

Comment: Neste caso na diretiva que criei tenho que colocar essa informação? Por exemplo:

return {  
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
  $(el).datepicker({
    locale: "pt-br"
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        var date = Date.parse(dateText) || 0;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
      });
    }
  });
} 

};
});